# What does "means-tested" mean?

Tags: meaning

Could you anybody let me know what "means-tested" mean in "How do minimum wage increases affect expenditures on means-tested public assistance programs

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Means_test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A **means test** is **a determination** of whether an individual or
> family is eligible for government assistance, based upon whether the
> individual or family **possesses the means** to do without that help.
>
> Today, **means-tested benefits** meaning that entitlement is affected
> by the amount of income and savings is a central feature of the
> benefit system.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Means_test)